# running PEAR commands returns 401 "Unauthorized"

Tags: php, pear

I am trying to install PHP Mess Detector via PEAR and getting these 401 `Unauthorized` messages. However, I can access the same files / URLs via browser without a problem. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I am on Windows, XAMPP, behind a proxy server

From command prompt, I run:

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@XX.XXX.X.XXX:80
```

Response:

```
config-set succeeded
```

I run:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpmd.org
```

I get:

```
Discovering channel pear.phpmd.org over http:// failed with message: channel-add:    
Cannot open "http://pear.phpmd.org/channel.xml" (File http://pear.phpmd.org:80
/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
( The server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web server  
is denied. Contact the server administrator.  )
))
Trying to discover channel pear.phpmd.org over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.phpmd.org" failed (channel-add: Cannot open 
"https://pear.phpmd.org/channel.xml"
(File https://pear.phpmd.org:443/channel.xml not valid 
(received: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
( The server requires authorization to fulfill the request.
Access to the Web server is denied. Contact the server administrator.  )
```

But I can open http://pear.phpmd.org/channel.xml in browser without a problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:

If i change proxy port to 8080, I get `407 Proxy Authentication Required` messages, so I believe that 401 errors are not caused by proxy but the remote host

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@XX.XXX.X.XXX:8080
```

I get:

```
Discovering channel pear.phpmd.org over http:// failed with message: channel-add:  
Cannot open "http://pear.phpmd.org/channel.xml" 
(File http://pear.phpmd.org:80/channel.xml not valid 
(received: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required 
( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request.
Access to the Web Proxy service is denied.  )
```

EDIT 2:

I checked, and this happens for any channel, so this is not related to mess detector. Probably firewall / proxy fault?

EDIT 3:

OK, I tested proxy settings in my browser. When I set port to 80, the web is unreachable, so 401 errors mean there is no connection or something? Proxy server port 8080 in browser settings works as expected. So, it appears that pear doesn't pass my credentials properly.

My username, password and proxy IP are correct - I checked million times.

```
pear remote-list

File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/c/categories.xml not valid 
(received: HTTP/1.1 407   Proxy Authentication Required 
( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request.
Access to the Web Proxy service is denied.
```

Comment: are you sure you are using your command with the enough system privileges?

Comment: Ah, you may be on to something. Not sure, I am able to ping remote sites and can use PHP in CLI mode, mysql etc.

Comment: Try to take a look at the proxy configurations and maybe try to add it to your post

Comment: OK, seems that I confused myself with proxy ports and messages. See EDIT 3 above.

Comment: It says 407 and not 401? So what is it? 407 means that the client must first authenticate itself with the proxy and 401 means that you have to set your authentication to do your action

Comment: @eliasah 407 for port 8080 (correct port in browser settings), 401 for port 80 (doesn't work in browser either)

Comment: Try to follow what is suggest by the Pear Manual (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.channels.php)